# zip file encryption

Tags: c++, c, binary, zip

I'm trying to block zip file open...

How to block it.... Is there any other methods except modifying zip header info.

My rosources are packed with zip file but I don't want to open it to users...

Please let me know it

Comment: If people _really_ want to extract your program resources, there is nothing you can do to stop them. A good interactive debugger (think IDA Pro) is pretty much all you need.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to have a little program that garbles the header of the zip-file
then when you need to unzip the file you restore the header. It is by far not a fool proof
method but it may deter some people (Of course your files shouldn't have the .zip extension
either since then they may be looking in the first place).

Another, probably better option is encrypt your zip-file either using the zip built in way of encrypting it our use one of the many standard encryption libraries out there.

Answer (score 1):

As said before, if you give away the data and the key (in whatever form), it's a matter of time and efforts to get those data extracted.

There can be several actions taken to make access to the data more complicated:

1. use password. The simplest to use
   and the simplest to crack.
2. protect various resources using
       different keys and always extract
       only those data that you need for
       each particular operation. This way
       you don't ever extract all the data
       at once and don't keep them
       unprotected.
3. use custom
       packaging and encryption, not
       standard ZIP. The more custom the
       solution is, the harder it will be
       to pick the data. Our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/)
       product can be used for this
       purpose. To make things even more
       complicated, you can read [an
       article](https://www.eldos.com/solfs/articles/5016.php).
4. obfuscate the encryption keys.
5. use hardware
   keys to protect access to the data
   (read the above article for
   information about hardware keys).

Answer (score 0):

You can give password protection to zip file.
Whoever has the password can only open the file.

From link http://www.dslreports.com/faq/8730,
Here is how to add password protection in Windows.

- Right click on the compressed folder
  and select “Explore.” In “File,”
- select “Add a Password.” Enter the
  password and confirm the password.